# What do I do with unused spackle

Tags: spackling-paste

Of course they don't have really small containers of spackle.  I haven't even used 1/8 of it - Is there anything you can do with the leftovers?  How long can you store it?

Comment: Use it! You can never spackle enough. :p

Comment: give your kids a bowling ball, guaranteed to put new holes in the walls.

Comment: Worst case, donate it to the local habitat-for-humanity or building materials resell center.

Comment: There are always holes to fill. I keep a list and do them all at once. In the cellar there are some really big holes to use up any leftovers. My kids laugh when they see me wandering around with the pot and the knife "any holes need filling?".

Answer (score 8):

Seal tightly and hope. I've had it stay good for a decade.

Worst that happens is you throw it out then.

Comment: +1 And press a piece of plastic wrap down on the surface of the spackle to reduce air contact.

Comment: Absolutely sprinkle just a tiny bit of water on top and seal it with plastic wrap before putting the lid on. Years vs. months.